# Manipulating QueryStrings in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, query-string

I've seen multiple examples and answers on StackOverflow explaining that this would be the recommended way to create a QueryString to manipulate.

```
NameValueCollection test = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
test.Add("hello", "world");
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
```

But all it returns is

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
```

What's going on? Simple .NET4 console application to test with (tried earlier Frameworks as well). If I don't feed it an empty string it starts working, but it seems odd that there are so many posts recommending this as a solution. Wrapped it in a try/catch statement as well just to see if anything strange was going on, no Exceptions are thrown. Am I really supposed to just give it a random string "a=b", then remove it from the NameValueCollection afterwards in order to get a usable HttpValueCollection?

My ultimate goal was using this with an UriBuilder, grabbing the Query property from it and feeding it to ParseQueryString. However sometimes there might be no query string, UriBuilder.Query will return an empty string...thus this issue came up.

**EDIT:** In case anyone was confused, what I am intending for it to print out is the query string equivalent of the collection. So if I were to add another value to the collection

```
test.Add("other", "value");
```

The result of the ToString() method should be

```
"hello=world&other=value"
```

**EDIT HI DAVE**
My claim? Why it doesn't work...
[image]

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: This works fine for me. I took your exact code from the question and it produced the results that you wanted. If I don't call `Add` then I get an empty string when I call `ToString()`

Comment: Tried all .NET versions: 1.1, 2, 3, 3.5, and 4. However I'm running on Mono (in linux). Just got around to finding a Windows test environment, and sure enough it works. Must be a bug in Mono's System.Web :(

Comment: Nicholi you are a nice guy and I love your dressed android avatar, but next time please tell from the beginning you are on another platform, tag your question with such crucial detail or I give you an iPhone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was an age-old bug in Mono (something I forgot to mention in my question!!).
I was using Mono 2.10.5 with MonoDevelop 2.6.
Seems to be no issues with Microsoft's System.Web.

[Just got it fixed now.](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=970)

Answer (score 4):

your code is wrong, to print the content of test you should do this:

```
foreach(string s in test.AllKeys)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", s, test[s]);
}
```

**Edit:** I don't get your point Nicholi, see this picture, I get the proper class `HttpValueCollection` also starting from empty string in parse method and not adding the hello key, see that my test.Add was commented out and AllKeys is empty.

so my `test.ToString()` is returning empty and **not** `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` as you mentioned in your question.

[image: My debug test]

what else do you want/need/ask/claim ? ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` is printed?  You said what to do, but not why to do it.

Comment: @Davide, you seem to be treating the return value of ParseQueryString as a plain old NameValueCollection. This is incorrect, it actually returns an HttpValueCollection (derived from NameValueCollection) which overrides the ToString method in order to return... a query string. So what it should print out is "hello=world". If I add another value to the collection, it would be "hello=world&other=value". Ya know... like a query string. As I've understood it that was the entire purpose of the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() method. Otherwise I would just make a NameValueCollection myself to do that.

Comment: Nicholi if what you ssy is true why op gets System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection when he does ToString as initially stated in the question?

Comment: I am op, and I don't know. That is why it is so confusing. If you feed ParseQueryString() anything other than an empty string it will work. But there are lots of StackOverflow answers which give this as a specific answer. I don't really have an initial querystring value to start with, which is why it would seem redundant to simply add one in construction but remove it immediately afterwards.